# How to call Web Services with WSDL

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, wsdl

How do you call a Webservice through javascript? I have a WSDL and I am trying to create a javascript so that I can type in a value on an input box and when I click ok I will get an WSDL response. I have the SoapUI and I can plug in some information and hit run and I get successful returns but I am not sure how to do that with in a Javascript.\

Any help will be gratefully appreciated! Since I can't find any syntax information on how to code this.

Comment: You need to look at AJAX.

Comment: When I look up information about the AJAX I can't find a whole lot of information about WSDL webservices. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: You asked how to call a webservice through Javascript. You format your WDSL request and use AJAX send it to your WDSL interface. The two aren't related, except that you can use one to make a call to the other. _What_ you send (and the response) is defined by WDSL; _how_ you send it is defined by AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a call I made with a Web Service I use on my site. The problem I ran into by using Javascript to make the SOAP call was an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. This was caused by making an HTTP request outside of the home domain. I eventually used PHP PEAR SOAP to connect to the service and it has been working flawlessly since.

My script: [Cross Domain SOAP request (php soap not an option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630697/cross-domain-soap-request-php-soap-not-an-option)